# show fields of group table in sql query that are not in a group function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how to do this:

I have a table `JOBS(IDJob, IDUser, Notes )` and a related table `JOBTIMES(IDJT, IDJob, JobTime, IDState)`

In table `JOBS` I have these records:

```
(IDJob, IDUser, Notes)
(1, 25, 'Table')
(2, 23, 'Chair')
(3, 25, 'Window')
```

And in table `JOBTIMES`

```
(IDJT, IDJob, JobTime, IDState)
(1, 1, '10:15:00', 1)
(2, 1, '10:16:15', 3)
(3, 1, '10:17:12', 2)
(4, 1, '10:18:00', 1)
(5, 2, '10:10:00', 2)
....
```

I want to show One row per job showing `Minimus time`, `max time` and `IDState` of row with Max time

I've made this query. It shows MinTime, and MaxTime, but how I show the idstate of MaxTime row, or last row of each job?

```
SELECT j.idjob, j.iduser, j.notes, MIN(jt.jobtime), MAX(jt.jobtime)
FROM JOBS j INNER JOIN JOBTIMES jt ON j.IDJob = jt.IDJob
GROUP BY j.idjob, j.iduser, j.notes
```

How I show idstate of row with `MAX(jt.jobtime)`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would create two sub queries, one for the max times and one for the min times. Join the three tables and then just select the idstate form the max table.

```
    SELECT
        j.IDJob
        , j.IDUser
        , j.Notes
        , max.JobTime
        , min.JobTime
        , max.IDState

    FROM
        JOBS j
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        IDJT
        , IDJob
        , MAX(JobTime) AS JobTime
        , IDState
    FROM
        JOBTIMES
    GROUP BY
        IDJT
        , IDJob
        , IDState
    ) max
    ON j.IDJob = max.IDJob
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        IDJT
        , IDJob
        , MIN(JobTime) AS JobTime
        , IDState
    FROM
        JOBTIMES
    GROUP BY
        IDJT
        , IDJob
        , IDState
    ) min
    ON j.IDJob = min.IDJob

    GROUP BY
        j.IDJob
        , j.IDUser
        , j.Notes
        , max.JobTime
        , min.JobTime
        , max.IDState
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions:

```
SELECT j.idjob, j.iduser, j.notes, MIN(jt.jobtime), MAX(jt.jobtime),
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN idstate END) as job_at_maxtime
FROM JOBS j INNER JOIN
     (SELECT jt.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDJob ORDER BY jobtime DESC) as seqnum
      FROM JOBTIMES jt
     ) jt
     ON j.IDJob = jt.IDJob
GROUP BY j.idjob, j.iduser, j.notes
```